# Testing for Null or Empty Intent with Extrasd

Tags: android, android-intent, null

I have an Activity that I would like to implement an either-or logic to begin with:

I have this line:

```
Username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userprofile");
```

If this is empty, I want it to assign username from somewhere else... such as

```
if (Username.equals("")) {
    Username = Rateit.username;
}
```

However, it of course crashes on that first line.

**Why am I doing this?**  This Activity will be a User Profile for currently logged in user if the extras is empty.  There are other scenarios where you click on other usernames (not you, the logged user), and it goes to SAME Activity with THEIR info.

I either need to find better logic or how to test for null.

LogCat as request on crash:

```
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.---.---/com.---.---.profile.ProfileFragmentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at com.---.---.profile.ProfileFragmentActivity.onCreate(ProfileFragmentActivity.java:85)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-16 14:39:24.088: E/AndroidRuntime(13467):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What error do you get when your program crashes? Please post the stack trace from the logcat.

Comment: added per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there aren't any extras, `getExtras()` returns null. So, it will throw an exception on `getString()`. You need to split up that line to check it for null.

```
userName = "";
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{
    userName = extras.getString("userprofile", "");
}
```

Also notice the added `""` argument in `getString()`, to avoid a null return there. This only works in API >= 12. The one-argument `getString()` available in all API levels will return null if the `"userprofile"` string extra isn't found, so you'll just need to null-check the returned string.

Comment: that was it.. though it said `getString` requires API 12 which is weird?

Comment: The two-argument `getString()` was apparently not added until then. Strange. Edited answer to reflect.